# Logistic regression - Transposing formulas

Tags: logarithms, logistic-regression

I am trying to understand the math behind Logistic regression. I am confused about transposing one formula to another.

Here is what I have:
Our regression formula
$$\ y = b_0 + b_1x$$

Our sigmoid function

$$\ p = \frac{1}{1+e^{-y}}$$

Our logistic function

$$\ ln(\frac{p}{1-p}) = b_0 + b_1x$$

From what I understand, we have to solve for y using the sigmoid function. I did this:

1. $$\ p = \frac{1}{1+e^{-y}}$$
2. $$\frac{1}{p} = 1+e^{-y}$$
3. $$\frac{1}{p}-1 = e^{-y}$$
4. $$\ln(\frac{1}{p}-1) = ln(e^{-y})$$
5. $$\ln(\frac{1}{p}-1) = -y$$
6. $$\ -ln(\frac{1}{p}-1) = y$$
   6 is y for our logistic function, but I don't see how can we get to our logistic function y $$\ ln(\frac{p}{1-p})$$

Can anyone help me transpose this or point me in the right direction?

If anyone downvotes me, please explain why in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-\log (\frac1p-1)=-\log(\frac{1-p}{p})=\log(\frac{p}{1-p})$$

Comment: I guess the part I was missing was changing the 1 into p/p in $\ -ln(\frac{1}{p}-1) = y$ and taking the reciprocal of the inside of the natural log in the intermediate step. 

$\ -ln((\frac{1-p}{p})^{-1})*-1$ => $\ln(\frac{p}{1-p})$