# Logit generalized equation

Tags: inverse, logistic-regression

The logistic equation and its transpose is available : [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2781233/logistic-regression-transposing-formulas)

The generalized logistic equation is available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function). The parameters of this equation can be varied to control its shape and range.
$$Y(x) = A+\frac{K - A}{\left(C + Qe^{-B(x - M)}\right)^{1/\nu}}$$

Based on these two sources, I have derived the equation for generalized inverse logistic function [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9t7B.png)
$$X(y) = -\frac 1B\log\left(\frac{\left(\frac {K - A}{y - A}\right)^\nu + C}Q\right) + M$$

However, I cannot control the shape and range as it can be done in the generalized logistic equation. At the end, I want to fix the x and y limits and generate different trends in that region. How can I achieve this?

Comment: As your function is indeed the inverse of the generalized logistic function, you have exactly as much control over its shape as in the original. I can only imagine that you are misunderstanding how that control works on the inverse vs the original. For instance, there are no limits on $x$ in either one. But $x$ is the output variable for you and the input variable in the original.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it.